# changing directories in a perl script to find modules

Tags: perl, module, directory-structure

If I have a script.pl for example in the path C:\folder1\folder2 when I use Cwd it will of course return C:\folder1\folder2 as my current working directory. I was wondering though if I could change my working directory within my script.pl using

```
chdir "C:/folder1";
```

so I can now look in C:\folder1 for any modules I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do exactly that, but it won't change where `use` and `require` look for the modules you are including. All it will affect is where file operations like `open` will look for files specified with a relative path.

What you need is [the `lib` pragma](https://metacpan.org/module/lib), like this

```
use lib 'C:/folder1';
```

at the head of your program. This will add the directory to `@INC` which is the built-in array of directories that Perl searches for included modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you shouldn't. Instead use [the `lib` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/lib) to include alternative module roots:

```
use lib 'C:/folder1';
use My::Module; # which is in C:/folder1/My/Module.pm
```